# Why JavaScript closure not work correctly with double parentheses?

Tags: javascript

When I use double parentheses this code return 1

```js
function a(){
  let x = 0;
  return function b(){
    x = x + 1;
    return x;
  }
}
a()();
a()();
console.log(a()());
```

But this code return 3.

```js
function a(){
  let x = 0;
  return function b(){
    x = x +1;
    return x;
  }
}
let y = a();
y();
y();
console.log(y());
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Think about how often `let x = 0;` gets run in the first sample, and in the second. That is the key to the answer.

Comment: From what I see it is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: In the first one, you're calling `a()` twice.  In the second one, you're calling `a()` once and reusing the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example runs `a` **three separate times**, so the execution of `a` a second or third time has no impact on the return value from other invocations of `a`.

But, in your second example, **you are assigning `y` to the function returned from your *single invocation* of `a`**, which sets up the closure. So now `y` holds a reference to the `x` variable used in `a`. Calling `y` a second time and then a third time uses the same, singe scope that the first invocation of `a` held, so the same `x` value is used throughout the code. And finally, since you invoke `y` three times, the same one `x` gets incremented 3 times and you get `3` as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some debug in your code can help to understand what is doing. In the first example, you are calling method `a` (that initializes variable `x`) and then invoking the function it returns (this pattern is executed 3 times):

```js
function a()
{
  let x = 0;
  console.log("Initializing x to 0!");
  return function b()
  {
    x = x + 1;
    console.log("Incrementing x, x now is: " + x);
    return x;
  }
}
a()();
a()();
console.log(a()());
```

On the second example, you call method `a` one time, and then you do multiple calls to the function it returns, so `x` is incremented multiple times:

```js
function a()
{
  let x = 0;
  console.log("Initializing x to 0!");
  return function b()
  {
    x = x + 1;
    console.log("Incrementing x, x now is: " + x);
    return x;
  }
}

let y = a();
y();
y();
console.log(y());
```

Also, you can found more details here: [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), that can help you to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is the same as this:

```js
// a()();
x = 0; x = x + 1;
//a()();
x = 0; x = x + 1;
//console.log(a()());
x = 0; x = x + 1; console.log(x);
```

Your second example is doing this:

```js
//let y = a();
x = 0;
//y();
x = x + 1;
//y();
x = x + 1;
//console.log(y());
x = x + 1; console.log(x);
```